# How to prepopulate Apex Class text box in Schedule Apex page? Any thoughts please

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have been developing a tool where there is a need to schedule a job. For that i do not want to duplicate the functionality which already exists which means i need the same features and functionality that is on Schedule Apex page. So i am going to use the standard Schedule Apex page just by redirecting to it.

Now the need is to pre-populate the Apex Class text class with a predefined schedule apex class. Is that possible? Is there a way to pass any query string parameter that would populate Apex Class text box? Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the links on this developer.force.com forum post [on url hacking](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009pbeIAA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inspect the source of the Schedule Apex page you will see that the selected Apex Class goes into a text input with the name `ac`. The text input is also connected up to some javascript that takes the value from the LookupPage and writes it back to the ac control.

[image]

At a guess I tried adding an `ac` query string parameter to the page request assuming the value would get copied into that corresponding HTML control.

[image]

It appears to work well. If you give it a valid value the warning doesn't appear.

Of course, you need to remember that this type of URL hacking carries no support from Salesforce. They may break this functionality at any time with changes to the UI.